# How do delegates solve cross-threading issues?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, user-interface, delegates, function-pointers

I know you can't call a GUI update function from a `background thread`, yet I can't see how creating a `delegate`, assigning the GUI update function to it, and then calling it solves this problem. How is this any different than calling the GUI update function itself? How does creating a `function pointer` (`delegate`) solve this problem?

Comment: the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) for `Control.Invoke` talks about this in length. that is probably your best place to go for an explanation.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran Read it but still do not understand *how* it solves cross-threading issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegates do *not* solve this problem, the Control.BeginInvoke() or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() methods do.  Only they know how to properly run code on a specific other thread, a feature provided by the message loop (aka dispatcher loop) that the UI thread uses.  Such a loop is the common solution to the [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).

These methods *require* a delegate object, passed as an argument.  So that they know what specific code needs to run on the UI thread.